# What is the difference between methods that have parentheses and methods that do not have parentheses?

Tags: python, typeerror, openpyxl

I'm working on learning OpenPyXL as part of the Automate the Boring Stuff textbook. My question has to do with the following line of code:

```
for row in range (2, sheet.max_row + 1): # Starts at the row 2 and steps by 1 until highest row
```

Why do I get a `Type Error: 'int' object is not callable` when I run the `sheet.max_row()` method, but not when I remove the parentheses? What is the difference between a method that has has parentheses - for example, the difference between `sheet.max_row()` and `sheet.max_row`. I've noticed that the `sheet.get_highest_row()` method was replaced by `sheet.max_row()`.

I've produced the code for the following problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""
readCensusExcel.py

Chapter 12 - Project: Reading Date From a Spreadsheet
This program retrieves data counts the total population and the number of census tracts for each county.

"""

import os, openpyxl, pprint

os.chdir('D:\\Python\\Projects - Automate the Boring Stuff with Python\\Chapter 12\\readCensusExcel')
print('Opening workbook...')

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('censuspopdata.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Population by Census Tract']
countyData = {} # creates a dictionary called countyData

#Fill in countyData with each county's population and tracts
print('Reading rows...')
for row in range (2, sheet.max_row + 1): # Starts at the row 2 and steps by 1 until highest row
    # Each row in the spreadsheet has data for one census tract
    state = sheet['B' + str(row)].value
    county = sheet['C' + str(row)].value
    pop = sheet['D' + str(row)].value 

    # countyData dictionary keys format: countyData[state abbrev][county]['pops'] or countyData[state abbrev][county]['tracts']

    # Make sure the key for this state exists, it will do nothing if the key already exists
    countyData.setdefault(state, {})
    # Make sure the key for this county in this state exists
    countyData[state].setdefault(county, {'tracts': 0, 'pop': 0})

    # Each row represents one census tract, so increment by one
    countyData[state][county]['tracts'] += 1
    # Increase the county pop by the pop in this census tract
    countyData[state][county]['pop'] += int(pop)


# Open a new text fill and write the contents of countyData to it

print('Writing results...')
resultFile = open('census2010.py', 'w')
resultFile.write('allData = ' + pprint.pformat(countyData))
resultFile.close()
print('Done.')
```

Comment: `max_row` is *not* a method, apparently, just an integer attribute.

Comment: `sheet.max_row` *isn not a method* it is an `int`.

Comment: `sheet.max_row` is a property which is a method masquerading as an attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add more detail, what you're referring to is an attribute, not a method/function. If we look back at classes, we can see the difference. Say I have a class called dog:

```
class Dog():
  def __init__(self, color, name):
    self.color = color
    self.name = name

  def sayName(self):
    print(f"My name is {self.name}")
```

What do we have? My class has two methods, **init**() and sayName(). These do something. I can create a new instance with init, like this:

```
rusty = Dog("black", "Rusty")
```

and I can have rusty say his name by:

```
rusty.sayName()
```

rusty is a dog and sayName() is a method. It's something dogs can do. But rusty also has self.name and self.color, and these aren't methods, they're attributes. We determined what these attributes were when we ran **init**(), but we could have attributes that don't directly come from being passed to init. I could add:

```
class Dog():
  def __init__(self, color, name):
    self.color = color
    self.name = name
    self.lastname = f"Mc{name[:-1]}erson"

  def sayName(self):
    print(f"My name is {self.name} {self.lastname}")
```

And now I have 3 attributes, one of which I didn't directly pass to the init method. If I create rusty now:

```
rusty = Dog("Black", "Rusty")
```

I can then call sayName() and it will print:

```
My name is Rusty McRusterson
```

However, I could also do this:

```
print(rusty.lastname)
```

And that will access the attribute and print it:

```
McRusterson
```

However, most methods don't print to the console, they return a value. Like this:

```
def sayName(self):
    return f"My name is {self.name} {self.lastname}"
```

This is where it can be confusing, because it's hard to know whether the value you're accessing is provided by a function/method, or by an attribute. Maybe, instead of writing the self.lastname definition in the init, I added another method:

```
class Dog():
def __init__(self, color, name):
    self.color = color
    self.name = name

def lastName(self):
    name_slice = self.name[:-1]
    lastname = f"Mc{name_slice}erson"
    return lastname

def sayName(self):
    print(f"My name is {self.name} {self.lastName()}")
```

Notice how I had to change self.lastname in my print statement into self.lastName()? That's because the value I want is no longer an attribute, but the result of a method. The only way to know that is to understand how it was written in the first place or scour the documentation on my wonderful dog library. To make it worse, I could also write lastName() as a method that creates an attribute .lastname, which I would get in my code like this:

```
rusty = Dog("Black", "Rusty")
rusty.lastName()
print(rusty.lastname)
```

Another hint, though, is that if something needs to have arguments passed to it, it's going to be a method or function. There are also conventions for casing, but that's not much of a guide. Hopefully that explains the difference, though!